# How to remove the empty element in multi dimentional string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, filtering

```java
String[][] array = {{"abcd",""},{"asdf",""},{"",""},{"",""},{"",""},{"",""}};
```

I want to remove the `{"",""}` elements from the array.

How can I do it in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Remove?

You cannot change the size of an existing array.

If you want to create a new array with only these elements, count the length of each array, create a new array based on those lengths, add elements to the new array.

```
String[][] array= {{"abcd",""},{"asdf",""},{"",""},{"",""},{"",""},{"",""}};
//Assuming you want a 1-D array
int valuesPresent = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < arrray[i].length; i++) {
        if (array[i][j] != "") {
            valuesPresent++;
        }
    }
}
//Now you know how many values are there, so initialize a new array of that size 
String[] answer = new String[valuesPresent];
//Now add all the values to it
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < arrray[i].length; i++) {
        if (array[i][j] != "") {
            answer[index] = array[i][j];
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

To get a 2-d array, easy to understand:

```
//Just reordered input so we can understand better
String[][] array= {{"abcd","zxcs"}, //Row 0, col 0 = abcd and col 1 = zxcs
                   {"asdf",""},     //Row 1, col 0 = asdf and col 1 = ""
                   {"",""}};        //Row 2, col 0 = "" and col 2 = ""
//Counts how many columns have values(are not equal to "") in each row
int rowsWithValues = 0; //Counts how many rows have at least 1 value. Here, 2 
for (int row = 0; row < arrray.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < arrray[row].length; col++) {
        if (array[row][col] != "") {
            rowsWithValues++; //Since there's a col with value for this row
            break; //If any one value has been found, no need to check other cols
        }
    }
}
//Now we know how many rows we need in the result array: 2 (row 2 has no values)
String[][] result = new String[2][];
//We need to add the 2 rows with values now
int arrayIndex = 0; //Points to next empty index in result[][]
for (int row = 0; row < arrray.length; row++) {
    int colsWithValues = 0; //Cols with values for each row
    for (int col = 0; col < arrray[i].length; col++) {
        if (array[row][col] != "") {
            colsWithValues ++; //Col with value found for this row
        }
    }
    //Eg. For row 0, colsWithValues will be 2, since 2 cols have values(abcd, zxcs)
    //We need to add these 2 cols as a single array to result
    String[] currentRow = new String[colsWithValues]; //Will be 2 here for row 0
    int rowIndex = 0; //Points to next empty column in currentRow[]
    for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
        if (array[row][col] != "") {
            currentRow[rowIndex] = array[row][col];
        }
    }
    //After this, for row 0, currentRow will be {abcd, zxcs}
    //Just add it to our result
    result[arrayIndex] = currentRol;
    //After 1st iteration, result will be {{"abcd", "zxcs"}, {}}

    //During 2nd iteration, arrayIndex == 1, currentRow == {"asdf"}
    //On adding it to result[1], result will be {{"abcd", "zxcs"}, {"asdf"}}
```

Comment: Nope, if you have `{{"abcd","aa"},{"asdf",""},{"",""},{"",""},{"",""},{"",""}};` your valuesPresent will be 3 bu you have 2 subarray in fact ;)

Comment: Sir, can I initiaze a two dimensional array of variable length

Comment: i wamt the multidementional array as the output

Comment: @DevilsHnd yes, `(array[i][j] != "")` implies it's empty, right?

Comment: @azro that was for the single dimensional array; valuesPresent == 3, which will result in a 1-D array with {"abcd", "aa", "asdf"}, which is expected for a 1D array.

Comment: @OmkarGhurye edited with a 2D array that should be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that, the nested array could be of any size not just of 2 elements.

Create a predicate that takes `Stream<String>` and checks if any element is not null and non-empty.

```
String[][] array= {{"abcd",""},{"asdf",""},{"",""},{"",""},{"",""},{"",""}};

Predicate<Stream<String>> arrayPredicate = element -> 
               element.anyMatch(ele ->Objects.nonNull(ele) && !ele.isEmpty());
```

Now stream over the original array and filter the inner array based on a predicate and collect it in a new array.

```
String[][] copyArray = Arrays.stream(array)
         .filter(arr -> arrayPredicate.test(Arrays.stream(arr)))
         .toArray(String[][]::new);

array = copyArray;  // reassign to array
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, don't compare two **Strings** for *equality* using `==` or `!=`, even for String Arrays:

```
if (array[i][j] != "") {
```

In the case above, it should be:

```
if (!array[i][j].equals("")) {
```

If you're not quite up to Streams yet then this is one way that might interest you:

```
public static String[][] removeNullStringRows(String[][] array) {
    if (array == null || array.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    int validCount = 0;  // Row Index Counter for the new 2D Array

    /* Find out how may rows within the 2D array are valid
       (where the do not consist of Null Strings {"", ""}).
       This let's you know how many rows you need to initialize 
       your new 2D Array to.         */
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            if (!array[i][j].equals("")) { 
                validCount++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Declare and initialize your new 2D Array. This is 
       assuming the column count is the same in all rows.  */
    String[][] array2 = new String[validCount][array[0].length];

    validCount = 0; // Used as an index increment counter for the new 2D Array

    // Iterate through the supplied 2D Array and weed out
    // the bad (invalid) rows.
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  // Iterate Rows...
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {  // Iterate Columns
            /* Does this row contain anything other than a Null String ("")?
               If it does then accept the entire Row into the new 2D Array.  */
            if (!array[i][j].equals("")) { 
                // Retrieve all the columns for this row
                for (int k = 0; k < array[i].length; k++) {
                   array2[validCount][k] = array[i][k]; 
                }
                // The above small 'for' loop can be replaced with:
                // System.arraycopy(array[i], 0, array2[validCount], 0, array[i].length);

                validCount++; // Increment our Row Index Counter for the new 2D Array           
                break;  // Get out of this column iterator. We already know it's good.
            }
        }
    }
    return array2;  // Return the new 2D Array.
}
```

To use this method you might do it this way:

```
// Your current 2D Array
String[][] array = {
                    {"abcd",""}, {"asdf",""}, {"",""}, 
                    {"",""}, {"",""}, {"",""}
                  };

// If the supplied 2D Array is null contains no rows 
// then get out of here.
if (array == null || array.length == 0) {
    return;
}
// Display the original 2D Array (array) in the Console window
System.out.println("The original 2D Array:");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length;i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
}

// Remove all rows that contain all Null String Columns.
// Make your Array equal what is returned by our method.
array = removeNullStringRows(array);

// Display the new 2D Array (array) in the Console window.
System.out.println();
System.out.println("The New 2D Array:");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length;i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
}
```

And your Console Window output should look like:

```
The original 2D Array:
[abcd, ]
[asdf, ]
[, ]
[, ]
[, ]
[, ]

The New 2D Array:
[abcd, ]
[asdf, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out all `null` and *empty* elements from this 2d array as follows:

```java
String[][] array = {{"abcd",""},{"asdf",""},{"",""},{"",""},{"",""},{"",""}};
```

```java
String[][] nonEmptyArray = Arrays.stream(array)
        .map(row -> Arrays.stream(row)
                // filter out 'null' elements and empty strings
                .filter(e -> e != null && e.length() > 0)
                // an array of non-empty strings or an empty
                // array if there are no such strings
                .toArray(String[]::new))
        // filter out empty arrays
        .filter(row -> row.length > 0)
        // an array of non-empty arrays
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

```java
// output
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(nonEmptyArray)); // [[abcd], [asdf]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private String[][] removeFromArray(String[][] source, String[] objToRemove) {
    return Arrays.stream(source)
                 .filter(element -> !Arrays.equals(element , objToRemove))
                 .toArray(String[][]::new);
}

void example() {
    final String[] empty = new String[]{"", ""};
    String[][] array = {{"abcd", ""}, {"asdf", ""}, {"", ""}, {"", ""}, {"", ""}, {"", ""}};
    array = removeFromArray(array, empty);
}
```

Something like that should work

Comment: @OmkarGhurye could you explain a little bit more what is the problem? It’s tested and it works in the example